# Combining 2 columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has 2 columns which I need to combine:

```
butterfly <- read.csv("Butterfly_Data_All.csv")

Red_Admiral_data <- butterfly[butterfly$Species == 'Red Admiral',]

pop_RA <- Red_Admiral_data$SINDEX` # where `SINDEX` is population index

summer_RA <- Red_Admiral_data$Average_Temp_May_June_July

winter_RA <- Red_Admiral_data$Average_Temp_Nov_Dec_Jan
```

`summer_RA` consists of the temperatures over 3 months in the summer, per observation of the butterfly species 'Red Admiral':

```
13.39 12.24 12.32 12.11 12.41 12.21 12.28 11.83 11.88 11.73 11.99
11.75 14.91 14.83 14.43 14.91 13.46 14.99 14.56 15.04 13.70 11.10
16.04 14.34 15.02 14.30 15.17 14.55 12.82 14.34 13.32 15.32 13.97
14.64 10.27 15.26 14.94 14.22 14.82 14.82 15.15 14.88 14.77 12.64
```

and `winter_RA` consists of the temperature over 3 months in the winter.

```
5.25  5.33  5.31  5.00  5.34  5.24  4.70  7.04  7.03  6.72  7.06
6.30  5.29  5.24  5.82  5.22  5.76  6.56  5.08  5.33  7.15  4.67
5.77  6.58  4.84  6.80  5.06  5.14  6.49  5.80  6.86  5.20  5.54
4.85  3.27  6.29  5.32  5.47  4.78  4.78  5.19  5.05  5.12  4.89
5.25  5.33  5.31  5.00  5.34  5.24  4.70  7.04  7.03  6.72  7.06
```

The dataset is huge, 21540 entries ommitted, and when I use the `merge()` function (even with increased memory) it crashes out the software.:

```
merge(summer_RA,winter_RA)
```

I am wanting to plot the population index for this species (`pop_RA`) against the summer and winter temperatures combined but so far can only create a separate plot for each. Hope this makes sense.

`dput(summer_RA)` output is:

```
13.49, 12.25, 13.41, 13.18, 13.67, 13.12, 13.72, 13.16, 13.53, 14.01, 13.02, 9.91, 11.51, 13.05, 12.9, 12.32, 13.3, 13.3, 13.03, 13.03, 9.75, 13.13, 13.23, 13.03, 13.45, 10.52, 10.52, 13.64, 
8.26, 12.88, 13.79, 12.46, 9.31, 13.3, 13.98, 13.11, 13.3, 12.85
```

`dput(winter_RA)` output is:

```
4.67, 4.16, 4.51, 4.55, 4.68, 5.13, 4.3, 4.39, 4.16, 5.02, 4.29, 4.17, 4.61, 5.18, 6.15, 6.15, 4.34, 6.15, 5.39, 5.39, 6.01, 5.18, 4.78, 5.39, 4.39, 5.02, 5.02, 4.48, 5.04, 4.13, 3.73, 3.16, 3.36, 4.13, 4.13, 4.13, 4.13, 3.29, 3.39, 3.29, 3.79, 3.79, 3.79, 4.43
```

`pop_RA` sample data:

```
 10   1   2   0   5   0   2   0   0   0   4   0  31   1  27  22 17   3   2  21  33  17  11  21   1  20   4   8  11  13  53   6  51   3  41  43  40   7   7   0   0   8  11  15  22   9   1   0  33   4   0   5   3  15   5   0   1   6   0   0   1   6   1   1
```

Comment: Are you just dealing with two vectors, or are these pieces of a `data.frame`? I doubt that `merge` is the right logic here. Please provide the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is about this-size sample of `summer_RA` (and for `winter_RA` as well). I don't know how `pop_RA` fits into this, but perhaps we need a representative sample of that as well.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post with more info. Hope this is all ok, I'm very new to R so not sure if it's right, thanks

Comment: Now that I know more of the data, `dput(summer_RA)` was not quite right, but your edit gave me a better idea of what we're dealing with: *one frame*. I don't know what you mean when you say you want to "combine" the two columns. Please edit your question and replace all of the other `dput` output with `dput(head(Red_Admiral_data,20))` (I used 20 rows, but really enough to play with). From there, please add what you expect out of this, *literally* ... a new column? a new frame? something else?

Comment: Hi Remy Bear! Please edit your  question as suggested by @r2evans. I think that your machine may be crashing because using `merge()` without any `id`column makes that one vector be recycled over the other, i.e., you are creating a data frame with every value  of vector2 being recycled over all the values in vector1. `merge()` is commonly used with any common id column to avoid that behavior, e.g.: `merge(x, y, by = 'id', all.y = T)` where `id` is a column present in each vector `x` and `y`

Comment: Using `merge` on two columns of the same frame is completely misinterpreting the purpose of `merge`. For a discussion of "merge" (and "join") operations, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/5706437/3358272, and realize that I think you should not be doing that..

Comment: Where are Red Admirals sighted, geographically, in the winter? Just for my knowledge, Costa Rica? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a simple solution for this:

Let's say you create a "season" data combining winter and summer. You can use `data.frame()` to combine the two datasets, like this:

```
season <- data.frame(summer, winter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that by "combine" you mean "plot together". It's just a guess.

I cannot use the sample data you provided, everything has different lengths (which is not correct for a `data.frame`), so I'll generate random data in the same "shape".

```r
Red_Admiral_data <- data.frame(pop_RA = c(10,1,2,0,5,0,2,0,0,0,4,0,31,1,27,22,17,3,2,21,33,17,11,21,1,20,4,8,11,13,53,6,51,3,41,43,40,7,7,0,0,8,11,15,22,9,1,0,33,4,0,5,3,15,5,0,1,6,0,0,1,6,1,1))
nrow(Red_Admiral_data)
# [1] 64
set.seed(42)
Red_Admiral_data$summer_RA <- rnorm(64, 12.6, 1.39)
Red_Admiral_data$winter_RA <- rnorm(64, 4.53, 0.78)
head(Red_Admiral_data)
#   pop_RA summer_RA winter_RA
# 1     10  14.50563  3.962712
# 2      1  11.81507  5.545983
# 3      2  13.10475  4.791962
# 4      0  13.47968  5.340035
# 5      5  13.16193  5.248168
# 6      0  12.45249  5.092285
```

### base R

```r
plot(summer_RA ~ pop_RA, data = Red_Admiral_data, type = "p", pch = 16, col = "blue", ylim = c(0, 16))
points(winter_RA ~ pop_RA, data = Red_Admiral_data, pch = 16, col = "red")
legend("bottomright", c("summer_RA", "winter_RA"), col = c("blue", "red"), pch = 16, bg = "white")
```

[image: base graphics scatterplot]

### ggplot2

`ggplot2` really prefers data in a long format, so we'll first reshape. (Reshaping/pivoting is not always a trivial thing, look for other questions related to using the `reshape2` package or `tidyr::pivot_*`.)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(reshape2::melt(Red_Admiral_data, "pop_RA", variable.name = "season"), 
       aes(pop_RA, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = season))
```

[image: ggplot2 scatterplot, same data]